# Sort array by string value with special sorting if value starts with number

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, array-multisort

This is an example array

```
$values[0] = array("id" => "1", 
            "name" => "100mA");
$values[1] = array("id" => "2", 
            "name" => "0.1mA");
$values[2] = array ("id" => "3", 
            "name" => "500mA");
$values[3] = array ("id" => "4", 
            "name" => "1000mA");
$values[4] = array ("id" => "5",
            "name" => "1000V");
$values[5] = array( "id" => "6",
            "name" => "500V");
$values[6] = array("id" => "7", 
            "name" => "0.5mA");
$values[7] = array( "id" => "8",
            "name" => "10mA");
$values[8] = array( "id" => "9",
            "name" => "TO-220");
$values[9] = array( "id" => "10",
            "name" => "TO-92");
$values[10] = array( "id" => "11",
            "name" => "white");
$values[11] = array( "id" => "12",
            "name" => "black");
```

I want to sort it by "name". The problem is that name is a string. The String could consist of chars but also of numbers and chars.
If "name" is a combination i want to sort it by the leading numbers.
I dont know how to to that. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the strings letter in ASCI-Code and sort them. Not sure if you would be happy with the result but try it.